# MySQL error 126 when adding ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out an issue I've been having. I have only around ~1m records in my table, and do about ~10 joins.

I'm not going to post the query, as I don't really think it's part of the problem. Basically, without an `ORDER BY m0_.id` clause, the query runs and returns results in 0.0056 seconds. Which isn't bad. But the moment I add that `ORDER BY`, the query fails with the following error:

`#126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_527_0.MYI'; try to repair it`

So I've been reading around, and apparently most of the time, this issue has to do with space. But that can't be it (can it?), because I've got 30Gb free and the *entire database* is only 200Mb. So I went further, and found the `sort_buffer_size` option. So I ran `SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 18446744073709551615`, which [apparently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) is the maximum for my platform. Sure enough, running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sort_buffer%';` returns

```
+------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                |
+------------------+----------------------+
| sort_buffer_size | 18446744073709551615 |
+------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I even tried limiting the query to 1 result, but no dice.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the query returns a lot of data and order by need creation of temp table and you do not have enough space for temp tables. You need increase the `/tmp` size.

Answer (score 0):

I think You'd better create a clone of this table and then rename them:

1. get create table query:

   SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
2. run query from (1) step change table_name to table_name_new
3. copy data from origin to new:

   INSERT INTO table_name_new VALUES (SELECT * FROM table_name);
4. try Your select with table_name_new

or try to create VIEW of Your heavy query without adding ORDER BY:

```
CREATE VIEW view_heavy_query AS HERE GOES YOUR HEAVY QUERY WITH JOINS;
```

and then do query like:

```
SELECT * FROM view_heavy_query ORDER BY field;
```